# Tkinter Treeview right most column not behaving correctly on resize

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, treeview

As shown on the GIF below, the right-most column of my tree view is not 'attached' to the right hand border. Why is this? Code at the bottom.

[image]

```
    self.tree.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='NSEW', padx=3, pady=2)
    self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=self.tree_scroll.set)
    self.tree_scroll.configure(command=self.tree.yview)

    self.heading('#0', text="Name", anchor='center')
    self.heading('version', text="Version", anchor='center')
    self.heading('author', text="Author", anchor='center')
    self.heading('description', text="Description", anchor='center')
    self.heading('runtime', text="Run Time", anchor='center')
    self.heading('maxtime', text="Max Time", anchor='center')
    self.heading('status', text="Status", anchor='center')
    self.column('#0', width=140, stretch=False)
    self.column('version', width=80, stretch=False)
    self.column('author', width=120, stretch=False)
    self.column('description', width=440)
    self.column('runtime', width=100, stretch=False)
    self.column('maxtime', width=100, stretch=False)
    self.column('status', width=100, stretch=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I don't know the type of column but

Can't you do something like that ?

```
self.column('status', width=parent.width - self.column('#0').widht  - self.column('version').width - ...etc..., stretch=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
container = Frame()
container.pack(expand=True)
```

Providing that your tree is in the container